# Create plugin for Qt Design Studio

Tags: c++, qt, qtplugin, qt-design-studio

## **Objective**

I am trying to create a plugin to have some custom widgets in Qt Design Studio.

## **Context**

I used to be familiar with Qt Creator, and made some plugins in previous projects.
For a new project, I need to create a plugin for Qt Design Studio, to allow users to manipulate customs widgets.

## **Problem**

My plugin is not visible or usable in Qt Design Studio.

## **Technical informations**

I use the Qt example "World Time Clock Plugin"(https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-worldtimeclockplugin-example.html).
I compile from Qt Creator 9.0.2, based on Qt 6.4.2 (MSVC 2019, x86-64), with the config "Qt 6.5.1 MSVC2019 64bit".
I try to add the plugin in Qt Design Studio 4.0.0, based on QT 6.4.0 (MSVC 2019, x86-64).

The compilation works. I add the plugin in Qt Design Studio with the Plugin Manager  ("About plugins / Install plugin"). I have no error message, and the dll is successfully copied in the target directory. But I cannot find it, or the widget, anywhere.

I tried everything I can found, but nothing works :-/